# Permissions issue Mac OS X Client -> Mac OS X Server

Tags: mac, unix, ssh, permissions, posix

I can't get access to a folder on our server and can't understand why. Perhaps someone will see what I'm overlooking...

Trouble accessing `/Library/Subdirectory/NextDirectory/`

User **joe** can `ssh` to the server just fine and `cd` to `/Library/Subdirectory/` however trying to cd into the next folder, `NextDirectory`, gives this error:

```
-bash: cd: NextDirectory/: Permission denied
```

both username **joe** & **bill** are members of the group **admin** and both can get INTO `Subdirectory` without any trouble...

```
hostname:Library joe$ ls -l | grep Subdirectory
drwxrwxr-x  3 bill   admin   102 Jun  1 14:51 Subdirectory
```

and from w/in the Subversion folder

```
hostname:Subdirectory joe$ ls -l
drwxrwx---  5 root   admin   170 Jun  1 22:19 NextDirectory
```

**bill** can `cd` into `NextDirectory` but **joe** cannot!?!  What am I overlooking? What tools do we have to troubleshoot this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check what groups Bill & Joe are in. Please provide output of `id USERNAME`

```
id bill  
id joe
```

Comment: BINGO! turns out joe is not a member of `80(admin)`. I used the, apparently, obsolete command `groups` from joe's machine but to my error i wasn't seeing the groups on the server. thanks for the help. and introducing me to `id`

Comment: Glad =) (need to add eight more characters, or superuser won't let me post)